# I'm having a problem installing npm vite with vanilla framework in vscode: npm init @vitejs/app = error (esbuild?)

Tags: npm, vite, esbuild

I'm new to Stackoverflow!

I'm having a problem initializing vite build for vanilla (I want to use with three.js) with npm in vscode...
Can someone please help me?

When I run in terminal:

`npm init @vitejs/app`

`Select a framework: vanilla`

`Select a variant:`

First of all, my options are not (like I see in many YouTube video tutorials)

`>JavaScript`
`>TypesScript`

they are

`>vanilla`
`>vanilla-ts`

If I go ahead with the 'vanilla' option am receiving error on npm install.

The problem seems to be with the esbuild?

`npm ERR! path /../prjct-vite/node_modules/esbuild`

`npm ERR! command failed`

`npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js`

Does anyone have any experience with this?

I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed.

npm -v7.19.1
node -v14.17.3

Does the logfile help decipher the problem?

```
133 error code 1
134 error path /../prjct-vite/node_modules/esbuild
135 error command failed
136 error command sh -c node install.js
137 error dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
137 error   Referenced from: /../prjct-vite/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild__
137 error   Expected in: flat namespace
137 error
137 error The version of the downloaded binary is incorrect: Command failed: /../prjct-vite/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild__ --version
137 error dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
137 error   Referenced from: /../prjct-vite/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild__
137 error   Expected in: flat namespace
137 error
137 error
137 error Install unsuccessful
138 verbose exit 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I am using (old) OSXElCapitan v 10.11.6

Comment: Do you have XCode dev tools installed?

Comment: Thanks tony19! I don't. I will look into that, thanks again for the suggestion.